# Display image from google cloud storage in flask website hosted on google cloud using python 3

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine, flask, google-cloud-storage

I'm am trying to make a website that takes input of text, generates an image, and then shows that image back in the html.

This works fine by writing the image to the static directory when I have the local test implementation, but when I push to google cloud I'm not allowed to write to the directory. I figured out how to save the image to my google cloud storage bucket instead, but now I can't get the image back to show in the html template.

I'm using Flask and python 3.7

Here is what I'm doing:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, send_file
import time
#import cloudstorage
import io, os
from google.cloud import storage
import tempfile

import functions

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SEND_FILE_MAX_AGE_DEFAULT'] = 0

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template("home_css.html")
    
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def my_form_post():
    text = request.form['text']
    URL = functions.main(text)
    print(URL)
    return render_template("return_img_css.html", picture_path = URL, screen_name = text)
```

Where the functions part contains a block that DOES SUCCESSFULLY SAVE the image to return the url of the image:

```
def make_plot():
    ....
    # NEED to SAVE THE IMAGE TO GOOGLE CLOUD
    client = storage.Client(project='meytweets')
    bucket = client.bucket('meytweets.appspot.com')
    savename =  'static/'+ screen_name+ '_network.png'
    blob = bucket.blob(savename)
    # temporarily save image to buffer
    buf = io.BytesIO()
    plt.savefig(buf, format='png')
    
    # upload buffer contents to gcs
    blob.upload_from_string(
        buf.getvalue(),
        content_type='image/png')
    buf.close()
    return blob.public_url
```

Where that URL usually looks like:
https://storage.googleapis.com/meytweets.appspot.com/static/twitter_network.png

And the HTML template looks like:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>{% block title %} Network for Twitter User: {{ screen_name }} {% endblock %}</h1>    
    <img src="{{ picture_path }}" >
{% endblock %}
```

Here is the app.yaml:

```
runtime: python37

env_variables:
    CLOUD_STORAGE_BUCKET: meytweets.appspot.com

handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: public
- url: /.*
  script: auto
```

As I wrote above, it does save the image to my google cloud bucket but then I can't get it back to show in the html:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwRS1.png)

I'm open to other strategies that do not write to google cloud, whatever works to display the image I produce in matplotlib is fine with me.

Answer (score 1):

When you run your app on serverless environment, only the `/tmp` directory is writable. You can't change the content of other directory, such as `/static`. In addition, the `/tmp` directory is an in memory file system, and thus, when the instance is killed, all the `/tmp` disappear.

Now, you can try to set the `/tmp` in the handlers. I never tested, not sure of the result and its consistency.

The other solution, is to save the image into Google Cloud Storage, and finally to generate your HTML with the image in the Google Cloud Storage, [publicly accessible of course](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public).

Comment: sounds like your suggesting that I try to save the image to /tmp  instead and then send the image from temp to the HTML? I was under the impression that I can only serve from  "static", but that I can use my google cloud storage bucket as static by using the handler: ``` handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: public

Comment: Serving from /tmp to HTML should work (I never tried, but by design, it shouldn't work). The Cloud Storage solution is better, but you need to make your bucket public to let anyone access to it.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since this question was asked, but I needed to do the same thing and got it working. I'm storing images in google object storage and inserting them into jinja2 templates as base64 encoded data in img tags.

Route:

```
@app.route("/view/<string:blob_name>")
def view(blob_name):
    bucket = get_bucket()
    blob = bucket.get_blob(blob_name)
    content = blob.download_as_bytes()
    image = base64.b64encode(content).decode("utf-8")
    return render_template('view.html', content_type=blob.content_type, image=image)
```

Template:

```
  <body>
    <h1>Image:</h1>
    <img src="data:{{ content_type }};base64,{{ image }}" />
  </body>
```

This solution works if flask is running on a serverless environment where you can't create temporary files and you don't want to make the data public.